# datepicker is not posting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, datepicker

I have tried most if not all of the suggestions on this forum, as well as a few others, but I'm still getting **0000-00-00** in MySQL DB even though it echos back correct format.
Here is the PHP code:

```
    <?php
    include_once("includes/form_functions.php");
    // START FORM PROCESSING
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.
        $errors = array();
        // perform validations on the form data
        $required_fields = array('location', 'date');
        $errors = array_merge($errors, check_required_fields($required_fields, $_POST));

        $location = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['location']));
        $date = mysql_prep($_POST['date']);
        $adult = mysql_prep($_POST['adult']);
        $child = mysql_prep($_POST['children']);
        $guest = mysql_prep($_POST['guest']);   
        $hg = mysql_prep($_POST['holyghost']);  
        $baptism = mysql_prep($_POST['baptism']);

            if ( empty($errors) ) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO attendance (
            location, date, adult, children, guest, holyghost, baptism
                        ) VALUES (
        '{$location}', {$date}, {$adult}, {$child}, {$guest}, {$hg}, {$baptism} 
                        )"; 
            $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            if ($result) {
                $message = "submission completed.";
            } elseif
                ($message = "This form cannot be submitted at this time.");
                 $message .= "<br />" . mysql_error();
            }
        }
   ?>
```

Here is the datepicker code:

```
     <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/jquery-ui.css" />
          <script src="javascripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
          <script src="javascripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
                });
          });
          </script>
    </head>
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure but if your db field is date then you have to send the year in `YYYY` format.

Comment: What format are you passing the date? And what is the type in your db table?

Comment: The format in the DB is yyyy-mm-dd. when I type yyyy for the date picker it gives 20132013-mm-dd. and is still rejected.

Comment: the DB field is date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use single code(') in your insert statement for date to fix this issue like below..

```
INSERT INTO attendance (
            location, date, adult, children, guest, holyghost, baptism
                        ) VALUES (
        '{$location}', '{$date}', '{$adult}', '{$child}', '{$guest}', '{$hg}', '{$baptism}' 
                        );
```

Always use single code(') & mysql_escape_string() function while passing value in MySQL

Comment: I think the (') are to make sure that it handles letters as well as numbers, in case of varchar. @pankaj... I might be wrong on that though.

Comment: My bad I looked back realizing that / and - are treated as letter values. that simple fix was it. what a noob mistake.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use MySQL's STR_TO_DATE() function to convert the string:

**INSERT INTO user_date VALUES ('', '$name', STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%m/%d/%Y'))**

1. Convert the string received from jQuery into a PHP timestamp—e.g. using strtotime():

   $timestamp = strtotime($_POST['_date']);

and then either:

format the timestamp using date():

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

pass the timestamp directly to MySQL using FROM_UNIXTIME():

INSERT INTO user_date VALUES ('', '$name', FROM_UNIXTIME($timestamp))

Answer (score 0):

i think is  based on mysql db  column type.  you need to change  $date value like that

```
`$explode_Date=explode("-",$date);`
```

`$date=date("d-m-Y, mktime(0,0,0,$explode_Date[1],$explode_Date[0],$explode_Date[2]));`

then try